# Best way to check if value exists for a key in ILookup<string, string> using linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

```
  ILookup<string, string> someList;
            Cricket Sachin
                    Dravid
                    Dhoni
            Football Beckham
                     Ronaldo
                     Maradona
```

```
bool status = someList.Where(x => x.Key == "Football").Where( y => y.Value == "Ronaldo")
```

should return true

```
bool status = someList.Where(x => x.Key == "Football").Where( y => y.Value == "Venus williams")
```

should return false

ILookup doesn't have value property, instead of looping over, is there a smarter way to get the result in few lines. the above code is not right, hoping something similar if its possible. I am new to Linq so learning better ways

Answer (score 7):

The object returned from of the [`ILookup<TKey, TElement>.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549314.aspx) property (which is what's called when you do `someList[...]`) is an `IEnumerable<TElement>`. So you can compare each item directly to your test value. Like this:

```
var status = someList["Football"].Any(y => y == "Venus Williams");
```

Comment: It will fail if there is no `"Football"` key within the lookup. You should call `someList.Contains("Football")` first.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Are you sure about that? I just tried it using a lookup created with `ToLookup` and it returned an empty set. Notice the [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyxt2e2h.aspx) docs specify an exception, but the [`ILookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549314.aspx) docs do not.

Comment: Hmm, Am I sure? Not really, but It would be kind a logic behavior. Thank you very much for pointing I was wrong!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I was really curious if you knew of a case where this could occur. The docs don't specify an exception, but they also don't mention that no exception will be thrown if the key is not found. Obviously if you wrote a custom `ILookup` you could make it behave any way you like.

Comment: You're right, it depends on implementation. However, I checked John Skeets' [eduLINQ version of ILookup implementation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-18-tolookup.aspx(http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-18-tolookup.aspx) and it returns `null` as well, instead of throwing an exception, so I think it's desired version of handling non-existing keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool status = someList.Where(x => x.Key == "Football").Any( y => y.Value == "Venus williams")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var status = someList.Any(grp => grp.Key.Equals("Football") && grp.Contains("Venus Williams"));
```

Explanation: ILookup is an IEnumerable of IGrouping - a grouping *has a* Key property, and *is a* list of string values

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.Any(x => x.Value == "value")`.

Might be wrong, but I think you'd want to do it in 2 steps, though, checking that the first (key) search succeeds before continuing to value search to ensure you're not doing an `.Any()` on a `null` object